# MPMoviePlayerController stills play after delete mp3 source file?

Tags: ios, mp3, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm writing a app to play media file.I use MPMoviePlayerController.
My source:

```
NSURL * mp3URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:mp3Path];
MPMoviePlayerController *mpv = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[mpv setContentURL:mp3URL];
```

But when i delete mp3Path,mpv stills play.
In this case,MPMoviePlayer creates a tmp file,load data from mp3Path to tmp path and play this tmp file?
Can anyone explain to me?Thanks so much.

Comment: you delete mp3 file? after playing? before playing?

Comment: yes,after mp3 plays 2 seconds,i delete mp3 file,it stills play to end of file.

Answer (score 0):

yes it creates a tmp file, thats why you have the  notifications for didloadfinish and didpreloadfinish if the file did load completely it is gonna play the whole song...